# Getting multiline sentence input in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to take multiple lines of string input (may contain spaces) in c++ using 2D char array but the loop gets terminated without taking any input for n=1 in the code:

When n=2, it takes only one input and when I try to print input[0], it prints blank. But for cout<

```
char input[100][100];
int n,i;
cout<<"Enter no of lines : ";
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" sentences : "<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin.getline(input[i],100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem when mixing formatted and unformatted input. After a formatted input, the internal buffer is positioned before the first blank character **and before the `\n`**. The bullet proof way would be to always use `getline` and then scan the first line to extract the number of lines. But for such a simple case, it is enough to use a dummy `getline` after reading the number of line to skip the end of line:

```
char input[100][100];
int n,i;
cout<<"Enter no of lines : ";
cin>>n;
cin.getline(input[0], 100);   // skip the end of line
cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" sentences : "<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin.getline(input[i],100);
```

But:

- you should always test `cin` after a read (what if the user types erroneously e instead of 4?)
- you should avoid `char arrays` and always use `string` in C++ (simpler, cleaner, less error prone)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter number of lines(say 4) you press 4 and then `enter` key. It is stored as `4\n` in stdin that is standard input. When you read using `cin.getline()` you are reading `\n`. You will have to use `cin.ignore` to ignore existing buffer in stdin. However using >> operator is better since it handles newlines.
For multiline input you can input a third parameter to `getline()`: a delimiter specifying what indicates the end of your input.